# Join JSON with a common attribute

Tags: json, ruby

I have a JSON with product items with a code, name and quantity. Sometimes items are duplicated (same code and name, different quantity). I'd like to sum the quantity of them in a single one.

Ex:

FROM

```
{ items: [{ code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 2.0 }, { code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 3.0 }, { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 4.0 }] }
```

TO

```
{ items: [{ code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 5.0 }, { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 4.0 }] }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
items_hash = { items: [{ code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 2.0 }, { code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 3.0 }, { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 4.0 }] }

items_hash[:items] = items_hash[:items].each_with_object([]) do |item, collected_items|
  if item_in_collected_items = collected_items.find { |i| i[:code] == item[:code] }
    item_in_collected_items[:quantity] += item[:quantity]
  else
    collected_items << item
  end
end

p items_hash
#=> { items: [{ code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 5.0 }, { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 4.0 }] }
```

Comment: This assumes the key `:items` is known. You might want to replace it with `items_hash.keys.first`, provided you assume that, as in the example, the hash has a single key. You have also assumed that if two hashes have the same value of `:code` they will also have the same value of `:name`. That's unclear from the question but would be an odd design for a hash. Lastly, the operation that modifies elements in `collected_items` is relatively inefficient; it has a computational complexity of `O(2)` whereas it could be close to `O(1)` with a different design.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yes, it is not a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

```
def group_em(h)       
  h.transform_values do |a|
    a.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
      h.update([g[:code], g[:name]]=>g) do |_,o,n|
        g.merge(quantity: o[:quantity] + n[:quantity])
      end
    end.values
  end
end
```

**Examples**

```
h = { items: [{ code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 2.0 },
              { code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 3.0 },
              { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 4.0 }] }

group_em(h)
  #=> { items: [{ code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 5.0 },
  #             { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 4.0 }] }
```

```
h = { items: [{ code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 2.0 },
              { code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 3.0 },
              { code: 1, name: 'C', quantity: 6.0 },
              { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 4.0 }] }

group_em(h)
  #=> {:items=>[{:code=>1, :name=>"A", :quantity=>5.0},
  #             {:code=>1, :name=>"C", :quantity=>6.0},
  #             {:code=>2, :name=>"B", :quantity=>4.0}]}
```

```
h = { items:   [{ code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 2.0 },
                { code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 3.0 },
                { code: 1, name: 'C', quantity: 6.0 },
                { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 4.0 }],
      returns: [{ code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 1.0 },
                { code: 1, name: 'A', quantity: 3.0 },
                { code: 1, name: 'C', quantity: 1.0 },
                { code: 2, name: 'B', quantity: 2.0 }]       
    }

group_em(h)
  #=> {:items=>[{:code=>1, :name=>"A", :quantity=>5.0},
  #             {:code=>1, :name=>"C", :quantity=>6.0},
  #             {:code=>2, :name=>"B", :quantity=>4.0}],
  #  :returns=>[{:code=>2, :name=>"B", :quantity=>3.0},
  #             {:code=>1, :name=>"A", :quantity=>3.0},
  #             {:code=>1, :name=>"C", :quantity=>1.0}]}
```

**Explanation**

See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values), [Enumerable#each_with_object](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-update), [Hash#merge](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values) and the form of [Hash#update](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. Here that block is:

```
do |_,o,n|
  g.merge(quantity: o[:quantity] + n[:quantity])
end
```

The values of the three block variables, `_`, `o` and `n`, are defined in the doc. I've used an underscore (a valid local variable) as the first variable--the common key--to signify that it is not used in the block calculation. That is common practice.

Note that:

```
h.update([g[:code], g[:name]]=>g)
```

is shorthand for:

```
h.update({ [g[:code], g[:name]]=>g })
```